# Creating event Flag

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, events, event-handling

I am creating event flag(i.e. first event, last event, other event( between first and last event). The events are occurring at each game (i.e. **gsm_id**). I have created the record of the first event(**First Event**) and last event (**Last Event**) in two different columns. you can look at the following table for more detail.

```
 gsm_id eventdatetime   matchdatetime   PreviousEventTime   First Event Last Event
2462794 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 20:09
2462794 8/11/2017 18:49 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 20:09
2462794 8/11/2017 19:13 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 18:49 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 20:09
2462794 8/11/2017 19:31 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 19:13 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 20:09
2462794 8/11/2017 19:40 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 19:31 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 20:09
2462794 8/11/2017 20:07 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 19:40 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 20:09
2462794 8/11/2017 20:09 8/11/2017 18:45 8/11/2017 20:07 8/11/2017 18:46 8/11/2017 20:09
2462795 8/12/2017 17:39 8/12/2017 16:30 8/12/2017 16:30 8/12/2017 17:39 8/12/2017 17:44
2462795 8/12/2017 17:44 8/12/2017 16:30 8/12/2017 17:39 8/12/2017 17:39 8/12/2017 17:44
2462796 8/12/2017 14:23 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:23 8/12/2017 15:27
2462796 8/12/2017 14:38 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:23 8/12/2017 14:23 8/12/2017 15:27
2462796 8/12/2017 14:42 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:38 8/12/2017 14:23 8/12/2017 15:27
2462796 8/12/2017 15:08 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:42 8/12/2017 14:23 8/12/2017 15:27
2462796 8/12/2017 15:27 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 15:08 8/12/2017 14:23 8/12/2017 15:27
2462797 8/12/2017 14:22 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:22 8/12/2017 15:17
2462797 8/12/2017 14:25 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:22 8/12/2017 14:22 8/12/2017 15:17
2462797 8/12/2017 15:17 8/12/2017 14:00 8/12/2017 14:25 8/12/2017 14:22 8/12/2017 15:17
```

Data can be downloaded from google drive  as follow:

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KPu8MBBd2X9tsV0sjMQQVQq4k9s5BYVs][1]

What i am trying to do is this.
I will create a new column to record the flag (string) (i.e. 'first event' where eventdatetime and First Event are the same, 'Last event' where  eventdatetime and Last event are the same, the rest will be assign as 'Other'.
I tried to use np.where method but it could only give me two arguments.
Can any one advise how to handle 3 argument to get abovementioned new column?

Thanks
Zep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['eventdatetime'] == df['First Event']
m2 = df['eventdatetime'] == df['Last Event']
df['flag'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['First event','Last event'], default='Other')
```

---

```
print (df)
     gsm_id    eventdatetime    matchdatetime PreviousEventTime  \
0   2462794  8/11/2017 18:46  8/11/2017 18:45   8/11/2017 18:45   
1   2462794  8/11/2017 18:49  8/11/2017 18:45   8/11/2017 18:46   
2   2462794  8/11/2017 19:13  8/11/2017 18:45   8/11/2017 18:49   
3   2462794  8/11/2017 19:31  8/11/2017 18:45   8/11/2017 19:13   
4   2462794  8/11/2017 19:40  8/11/2017 18:45   8/11/2017 19:31   
5   2462794  8/11/2017 20:07  8/11/2017 18:45   8/11/2017 19:40   
6   2462794  8/11/2017 20:09  8/11/2017 18:45   8/11/2017 20:07   
7   2462795  8/12/2017 17:39  8/12/2017 16:30   8/12/2017 16:30   
8   2462795  8/12/2017 17:44  8/12/2017 16:30   8/12/2017 17:39   
9   2462796  8/12/2017 14:23  8/12/2017 14:00   8/12/2017 14:00   
10  2462796  8/12/2017 14:38  8/12/2017 14:00   8/12/2017 14:23   
11  2462796  8/12/2017 14:42  8/12/2017 14:00   8/12/2017 14:38   
12  2462796  8/12/2017 15:08  8/12/2017 14:00   8/12/2017 14:42   
13  2462796  8/12/2017 15:27  8/12/2017 14:00   8/12/2017 15:08   
14  2462797  8/12/2017 14:22  8/12/2017 14:00   8/12/2017 14:00   
15  2462797  8/12/2017 14:25  8/12/2017 14:00   8/12/2017 14:22   
16  2462797  8/12/2017 15:17  8/12/2017 14:00   8/12/2017 14:25   

        First Event       Last Event         flag  
0   8/11/2017 18:46  8/11/2017 20:09  First event  
1   8/11/2017 18:46  8/11/2017 20:09        Other  
2   8/11/2017 18:46  8/11/2017 20:09        Other  
3   8/11/2017 18:46  8/11/2017 20:09        Other  
4   8/11/2017 18:46  8/11/2017 20:09        Other  
5   8/11/2017 18:46  8/11/2017 20:09        Other  
6   8/11/2017 18:46  8/11/2017 20:09   Last event  
7   8/12/2017 17:39  8/12/2017 17:44  First event  
8   8/12/2017 17:39  8/12/2017 17:44   Last event  
9   8/12/2017 14:23  8/12/2017 15:27  First event  
10  8/12/2017 14:23  8/12/2017 15:27        Other  
11  8/12/2017 14:23  8/12/2017 15:27        Other  
12  8/12/2017 14:23  8/12/2017 15:27        Other  
13  8/12/2017 14:23  8/12/2017 15:27   Last event  
14  8/12/2017 14:22  8/12/2017 15:17  First event  
15  8/12/2017 14:22  8/12/2017 15:17        Other  
16  8/12/2017 14:22  8/12/2017 15:17   Last event
```